# Storybook with react-scripts@next and css modules

Tags: create-react-app, css-modules, storybook, react-scripts

I tried react-scripts@next `2.0.0-next.66cc7a90` (create-react-app v2) because support for css modules has been added. Unfortunately, css modules are ignored by storybook. Any quick fix I could do?

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to create a `webpack.config.js` in the `.storybook` folder to enable css modules.

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /\.module\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: false,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.module\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {},
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: still getting error `SyntaxError

(1:1) Unknown word

> 1 | var content = require("!!../../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--11-1!./style.module.css");`

Answer (score 0):

Use Storybook preset addon to add CSS Modules capabilities.

[How to use css-modules with storybook 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70042915/how-to-use-css-modules-with-storybook-6/72398680#72398680)

#### Installation

```
npm install -D storybook-css-modules
```

#### Configuration

Next, update .storybook/main.js to the following:

```
// .storybook/main.js

module.exports = {
  stories: [
    // ...
  ],
  addons: [
    // Other Storybook addons

    "storybook-css-modules", //  The addon registered here
  ],
};
```