# How to use css-modules with storybook 6

Tags: storybook, css-modules

My css-module is not working with Storybook. There are not any error, it is only not working. I don´t understand what is the problem. This is the image of how storybook is rendering the button:

[image: Image without css]

**Button.js** file:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import style from "./styles.module.css";

const Button = ({ type, children }) => (
  <button className={style.button}>{children}</button> 
);

Button.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  type: PropTypes.string,
};

Button.defaultProps = {
  children: "primary",
  type: "primary",
};

export default Button;
```

**Button.stories.js** file:

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "./Button";

export default {
  component: Button,
  title: "Test/Button",
};

const Template = (args) => <Button {...args} />;

export const Primary = Template.bind({});
Primary.args = {
  children: "xx ",
};

export const Secondary = Template.bind({});
Secondary.args = {
  children: "xx ",
  type: "secundary",
};
```

**styles.module.css** file:

```
.button {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid var(--colors-transparent);
}

.test {
  background: red;
  color: var(--colors-white);
}

.type-primary {
  background: red;
  color: var(--colors-white);
}

.type-secundary {
  background: rgb(12, 177, 163);
  color: var(--colors-white);
}
```

**package.json** file:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.3.12",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.3.12",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.3.12",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.3.12",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3"
  }
```

I have tried these other options

```
<button className={style["button"]}>{children}</button>
```

**Maybe some idea how to solve it?**

Comment: Did you manage to fix the issue?

Comment: @SlavaZoref yes, you can see the link in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

@Slava Zoref you can see this video [css-modules storybook 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAyyPgvbkV4&list=PLKBvDYynKmlV91NjrOx11ZmKDlsxBeijc&index=15) minute 15:52 into .storybook/main.js you can write this code:

```
async function supportCssModules(config) {
  // console.log('1=================================')
  // console.log('>>>config', config.module.rules)
  // console.log('1=================================')

  config.module.rules.find(
    (rule) => rule.test.toString() === '/\\.css$/'
  ).exclude = /\.module\.css$/

  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.module\.css$/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  })

  return config
}

module.exports = {
  stories: [
    '../atomDesign/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
    // "../ejemplos/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)",
    // "../stories/**/*.stories.mdx",
    // "../stories/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials', //,'storybook-css-modules-preset',
  ],
  // FIXME: Support CSS Modules for Storybook
  webpackFinal: supportCssModules,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Storybook preset addon to add CSS Modules capabilities.

### Installation

```
npm install -D storybook-css-modules
```

### Configuration

Next, update .storybook/main.js to the following:

```
// .storybook/main.js

module.exports = {
  stories: [
    // ...
  ],
  addons: [
    // Other Storybook addons

    "storybook-css-modules", //  The addon registered here
  ],
};
```

By default this preset configured CSS Modules